# Alternative proof for Dini's theorem. Is it correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, compactness, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, $f_n : X \to \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of continuous functions, $f_{\infty} : X \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Now suppose that $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and that for each $x \in X$ the sequence (of real numbers) $\{ f_n (x) \}$ is monotonic (not necessarily all monotonic in the same way, there could exist $x$ such that $f_n (x)$ is monotonically increasing and $y$ such that $f_n (y)$ is monotonically decreasing). Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly. I think i found a simple proof of this theorem but i'm not sure it works.

Let's assume by way of contradiction that the convergence is not uniform. Therefore there exists a positive real number $\rho > 0$ such that $\sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x)-f_{\infty}(x)| \geq 2 \rho$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For each one of these $n$'s, choose $x_n \in X$ such that $|f_n (x_n) - f_{\infty} (x_n)| \geq \rho$. Because we have infinitely many of these $n$'s and each $x_n$ can be either such that $f_N (x_n)$ is monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing (wrt to $N$), there are either infinitely many of these $n$'s such that $f_N (x_n)$ is monotonically increasing or infinitely many of these $n$'s such that $f_N (x_n)$ is monotonically decreasing. Suppose the first one is true (the other case is identical). Then there exists a strictly increasing sequence $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $k \geq 1$ $|f_{\infty} (x_{n_k}) - f_{n_k} (x_{n_{k}})| \geq \rho$ and $f_N(x_{n_k})$ is monotonically increasing. Now, because $f_N (x_{n_k}) \to f_{\infty} (x_{n_k})$ as $N \to \infty$ and $f_N(x_{n_k})$ is monotonically increasing, we get $f_{n_k}(x_{n_k}) \leq f_{\infty} (x_{n_k})$, and so $f_{\infty} (x_{n_k}) - f_{n_k} (x_{n_{k}}) \geq \rho \iff f_{\infty} (x_{n_k}) \geq f_{n_k} (x_{n_k}) + \rho$. Now, this, together with the monotonicity, implies that for each fixed positive integer $N$ we have $f_{\infty} (x_{n_k}) \geq f_{N} (x_{n_k}) + \rho$ for big enough $k$. Now, $X$ is compact, therefore ${x_{n_k}}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{ x_{n_{k_t}}\}$ converging to a point $x_0 \in X$. So we get, for $t$ big enough, $f_{\infty} (x_{n_{k_t}}) \geq f_{N} (x_{n_{k_t}}) + \rho$. Taking the limit as $t\to \infty$, because of the continuity we get $f_{\infty} (x_0) \geq f_N (x_0) + \rho$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Taking the limit as $N \to \infty$, we get the contradiction $f_{\infty} (x_0) \geq f_{\infty}(x_0) + \rho$

Comment: I can see no mistake. Except that according to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification, "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct even when $X$ is any sequentially compact space. Good job!